# Access secure services from ArcGIS Portal with API JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal, proxy

I was reading this [tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/arcgisonline/set-up-authenticated-services/), that explains how to access secured services on ArcGIS Online. But I wonder if there is a way to do the same but with Portal and access my secured own data.

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the result? Please [Edit] the question.